# CascadeType for "getOrCreate" behavior with Hibernate child entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have two entities a and b, that rely on another entity c, while c can be considered more like a static table. A and B entities can have a reference on existing c entities.

My code works if I create an EntityC which does not exist yet, see below:

```
public class EntityA {

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private EntityC entityC;

}
```

I save the objects with

```
EntityA a = new EntityA();
a.setEntityC(new EntityC("MyEntity"));
repository.save(a);
```

However, I´d like to reuse the EntityC with name "MyEntity" now with EntityB in case it exists already.

```
EntityA a = new EntityA();

Optional<EntityC> existingEntity = entityCRepository.findEntityCByName("MyEntity)

a.setEntityC(existingEntity.orElse(new EntityC("A Name")));

repository.save(a);
```

CascadeType.All leads now to

> nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached
>   entity passed to persist: com.mypackage.EntityC

So I switched to **CascadeType.MERGE** which does exactly what I want, in case the entry already exists.

**How can I combine those two CascadeTypes in order to have both withouth the need of implementing extra logic?**

Comment: chain the cascadeTypes to include all the types you need?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer it does not work in this case

Comment: CascadeType.ALL includes CascadeType.MERGE, so I believe there is something else happening here. How are your transaction boundaries set?